# Mysql setting default value to be items auto increment key

Tags: sql, mysql

Just doing a site which requires multiple items to be reordered by AJAX.

When I create a given object in the database, I want to set the position column to the value of the rows' primary key upon creation.

How would I do this please?

Comment: Interesting question. Given the limited support for default values in MySQL, I wonder whether it can be done with a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A citation from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html#id3130880):

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column. See Section 10.3.1.1, “TIMESTAMP Properties”.

You can though obtain the id value on selection instead:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(position, id) as position ...
```

Comment: Thankyou, ill just do it with code and manulaly update after creation