# mysql insert duplicate values into table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values into a mysql table using python,I have some values but i donot consider whether duplicate keys/non duplicate but i want every values to be inserted.

For my mysql coding what changes should i make to insert duplicates?

```
   for name,hobby in p: 
       print name,hobby

   cursor.execute(
   '''INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby)
      VALUES (%s, %s)''',
     (name,hobby))
```

I get the following error!

```
   IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'Leelal' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

Please help me in getting the duplicate values into the table!

Table schema:

```
Id | Names | Hobby
```

Is there a way to auto increment Id as long as the Names and Hobby present in list?

Comment: Please show us the table schema you have, and the keys/indexes it has. There's no way you can both add duplicates and preserve your primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an attribute (column) in the table is a primary key (or unique), it can never accept duplicates. As long as your primary key (may be ID) do not have duplicates, you can pretty much insert duplicates For example,

```
ID   |   Name   |   Hobby  |
1        John       Play
2        John       Play
3        Steve      Running
4        Steve      Running
```

(Make sure that you set your primary key to auto increment. Here is the tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

```
CREATE TABLE Hobbies
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Hobby varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: but i need to increment id as the Names and Hobby present,so does it increment automatically/should i make changes?

Comment: @user3886307 If your ID is primary key, then yes, your ID would be automatically be incremented

Comment: @GravityM - Is that true in MySQL? If they only set it as the primary key does it auto increment? I would suspect that they need to do the AUTO_INCREMENT.  Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714787/mysql-setting-default-value-to-be-items-auto-increment-key) post, it does not appear you can make it a function to increment it for you.

Comment: @user3886307 Yes, ID is of type integer and you should set the Auto Increment.

Comment: how to set the Auto Increment?

Comment: See my answer. ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the problem is that your Details table has a primary key setup. In order to insert duplicates, you would need to remove the primary key, or change it to be unique enough that it's not considered a duplicate.

Look at your Table create script, I would assume you have something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Hobby varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Name)
)
```

Remove the PRIMARY KEY.

If you want to have Id as the primary, create your table something like this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Hobby varchar(255),
)
```